# Merge and inverleave rows of two dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Suppose we have:

```
>>> df1
   A  B
0  1  a
1  2  a
2  3  a
3  4  a

>>> df2
   A  B
0  1  b
1  2  b
2  3  b
3  5  b
```

I would like to merge them on "A" and then list them by interleaving rows like:

```
   A  B
0  1  a
0  1  b
1  2  a
1  2  b
2  3  a
2  3  b
```

I tried merge but it list them column by column. For example if I have 3 or more data frames, merge can merge them on some columns, but my problem would be then to interleave them

Comment: What means merge? If no match row is removed?

Comment: By merge I mean inner merge (I mean common rows based on a colomn, here A)

Comment: Or `pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values(by='A', kind='stable')` if you want to sort by A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need match by `A` filter rows by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), pass to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1[df1.A.isin(df2.A)], 
                 df2[df2.A.isin(df1.A)]]).sort_index(kind='stable')
print (df)
   A  B
0  1  a
0  1  b
1  2  a
1  2  b
2  3  a
2  3  b
```

EDIT:

For general data is possible sorting by `A` and create default index for correct interleaving:

```
df = (pd.concat([df1[df1.A.isin(df2.A)].sort_values('A', kind='stable').reset_index(drop=True), 
                 df2[df2.A.isin(df1.A)].sort_values('A', kind='stable').reset_index(drop=True)])
        .sort_index(kind='stable'))
```

Comment: thanks, it merges them on "A"? because I don't see you use "A"

Comment: I modfied the question to say A isn't equal for both

Comment: Thanks, it works for my need but yet its not general. For example what if I have 3 or more dataframes? Merge can merge them, but my problem was to interleave them

Comment: @Ahmad - so `sort_index()` not working?

Comment: I currently concat and sort them by "A" and it works for my need. I was worrief for future use and I test it later.